# What is a good way to get animals?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to make an animal farm in Minecraft – Pocket Edition, but I cant seem to catch them. Is there a good way to catch them or make them spawn in a specific area?

Answer (score 1):

To catch animals, make a hallway to push them into so that they go to your farm.

Answer (score 1):

Build a 2x2 hole in the ground and put torches in it. At night animals will go into it. Surround the hole with torches and build it where you think animals will spawn. It must be two holes deep or they will not go down.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 0.5.0 Alpha, then there is absolutely no way to do it except by pushing it into the farm. It is also pretty useless because you can't breed the animals. You can just move to an area where there is lots of animals. But if you have 0.8.0 alpha then you can use wheat to make them follow :)

Answer (score 0):

You can dig trenches and lead those trenches to a place where you want to keep your animals.

I got sheep, pigs, cows, and chickens by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Dig a hole in the ground and then push the animal in. 2x2 is the best size for me.

Answer (score -3):

Grow wheat! To grow wheat: take a hoe and tap a grassy block some times. A thing of seeds will pop up. Collect those, take the hoe wherever, and tap it. Once you have done all of that, just plant the seeds, wait a few days, collect the wheat by tapping and holding the finished crop (yellowish with a brown top), then collect the wheat along with more seeds. Pull the wheat out and show it to an animal. It should follow you! This only can be done on 0.8.0 update, and when you get the update you can grow carrots so pigs can follow you. This is what each animal can be lured by.

Chickens: wheat seeds

Cows: wheat

Sheep:wheat

Pigs: carrots and potatoes

Comment: They don't follow wheat in PE yet.